# I want to dualboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, windows

I want to dualboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04, can someone please show me every step for doing so. Please don't send links to videos, just type it for me please. I want to dual boot on one single hard drive. Which means, installing both operating systems in two different partitions, and I want the grub menu, to ask which operating system I want to boot in. Thank you.

Comment: It is a dup of some other Question but can't find it, I know It has been ask before.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this..

[Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of step-by-step tutorials on the internet.

[Tutorial 1](http://linux.about.com/od/LinuxNewbieDesktopGuide/ss/The-Ultimate-Windows-81-And-Ubuntu-Dual-Boot-Guide.htm)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Or maybe just a have a look on the amazing YouTube videos which are explaining everything step-by-step.

Also I am pretty sure that there are already plenty of explanations in this forum.